# How to vertically center/align text next to <pre> tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically centre the "Credit Card" text that is next to the pre-formatted credit card number. How do I get it so the "Credit Card" text is in line with "**** **** **** 0000"?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" checked></label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        Credit Card <pre style="margin-left: 8px; float: right; padding: 5px; background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px;">**** **** **** 0000</pre>
    </label>
</div>
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Comment: Can you use `CSS` external stylesheet or online inline styles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove `float: right` and add `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" checked></label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        Credit Card <pre style="margin-left: 8px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; padding: 5px; background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px;">**** **** **** 0000</pre>
    </label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look into this:

```
<div class="form-group" align="center" >
    <input type="radio" checked>
    <label>
        Credit Card <pre style="margin-left: 8px; display: inline; padding: 5px; background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px;">**** **** **** 0000</pre>
    </label>
</div>
```